# RSA encryption and decryption C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I make a code that encrypt file using AES and encrypt the new AES key using RSA and then embed all in an image using lsb steganography. when i make the encryption and decryption in the same debug the code run rightly but when i make the encryption in one debug then close the application and run the decryption in another debug the decryption code don't run rightly, when i trace the code in this case i find that the problem is in `RSAdecryption()`function because it return null in this case.
the encryption code is

```
 EncryptFile(pass_txt.Text, loadedFilePath, output);
       fileContainer = File.ReadAllBytes(output);
       hashcode = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(fileContainer);
       Newpassword = CreateRandomPassword(pass_txt.Text.Length);

       Newpasswordbytes = Byteconverter.GetBytes(Newpassword);
       RSAplain= Combine(hashcode,Newpasswordbytes);
       RSAcipher = RSAencryption(RSAplain, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false);
       byte[] header = new byte[3];
       int fileLength = fileContainer.Length;
       header[0] = (byte)((fileLength >> 16) & 0xff);
       header[1] = (byte)((fileLength >> 8) & 0xff);
       header[2] = (byte)(fileLength & 0xff);

       bytestobehidden = Combine(header, fileContainer);
       //byte[] enchashandnewpass = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
       bytestobehidden = Combine(bytestobehidden, RSAcipher);
       fileSize = bytestobehidden.Length;
        if (8 * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1) < fileSize + fileNameSize)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File size is too large!\nPlease use a larger image to hide this file.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

       StegoLayer();
```

and the decryption code is

```
byte[] bytestobedecrypted= ExtractLayer();
       int fileLength = (int)(bytestobedecrypted[0] << 16) +
             (int)(bytestobedecrypted[1] << 8) +
             (int)bytestobedecrypted[2];

       byte[] filebytes = new byte[fileLength];
       byte[] RSACipher = new byte[bytestobedecrypted.Length - fileLength - 3];
       System.Array.Copy(bytestobedecrypted, 3, filebytes, 0, fileLength);
       System.Array.Copy(bytestobedecrypted, fileLength + 3, RSACipher, 0, bytestobedecrypted.Length - fileLength - 3);
        byte[] hashplusnewpass = RSAdecryption(RSACipher, RSA.ExportParameters(true), false);
        byte[] newpass = new byte[hashplusnewpass.Length-32];
        byte[] hash=new byte[32];
        Array.Copy(hashplusnewpass, 0, hash, 0, 32);
        Array.Copy(hashplusnewpass, 32, newpass, 0, newpass.Length);
        string newpasswrd = Byteconverter.GetString(newpass);
        //Array.Copy(bytestobedecrypted, 0, filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length - 1);
        if (File.Exists(DSaveFilePath + "\\ext" + resFName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File \"ext" + resFName + "\" already exist please choose another path to save file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(DSaveFilePath + "\\ext" + resFName, filebytes);
            string infile = DSaveFilePath + "\\ext" + resFName;
            string outfile = DSaveFilePath + "\\dec" + resFName;
            DecryptFile(decpass_txt.Text, infile, outfile);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Decrypted file has been successfully saved.";
           MessageBox.Show("The password for next session is" + newpasswrd, "information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

the `RSAencryption()` and `RSAdecryption()` are

```
public static byte[] RSAencryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAkey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
try
{
    byte[] EncryptedData;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAkey);
        EncryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);

    }
    return EncryptedData;
}
catch (CryptographicException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    return null;
}
}
public static byte[] RSAdecryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAkey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
try
{
    byte[] DecryptedData;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAkey);
        DecryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
    }
    return DecryptedData;
}
catch (CryptographicException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    return null;
}
}
```

i define the RSA provider in the public variables

`RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();`

Comment: what exception you get in RSAdecryption method ?

Comment: it's a bad data exception and that cause the `RSAdecryption()` method return null and the next code line after it make a null reference exception

Comment: What have you done with regards to debugging? Did you print out the input of the `RSAdecryption` function in hexadecimals? Why do you think your current exception handling and returning `null` is an acceptable way of handling the exception?

Comment: the output of `RSAdecryption` method is a hash code+new password i print out this new password to the user in message box,the `RSAdecryption` give me a `bad data` exception and when i trace it i found that it return` null`